# Google maps doesn't display on all phones.

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, android-maps

I'm currently working with other friends on a small android project that uses the map.

At first we all could view the map. Then we exported it to an APK with the map key from Google and all the phones we installed it on works. But now something messed up in our SVN after that and only one of our four phones can see the map now when we install it via debugging.

How can we change it back to the old way so that all four phones can see the map again?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Mind Reader or Crystal Ball](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/133242)

Comment: You have version control. Learn how to bisect (manually, by hand, or using some tool) a set of svn revisions (changesets in other systems,that is, a series of diffs, showing what changed between now and then), and locate what you changed, that broke your code. Nobody else can do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you're building app on different machines, but maps api key is the same for all machines(i.e. debug keys are different on different machines, but map key is the same)?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't thinking when I was asking for help. What happened was I went back and got another map api key from google. But it kept saying my has was invalid. This was because java7 defaults to SHA-1 instead of MD5.